# Asymptotic stability implies the existence of a strong Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, uniform-convergence, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am having trouble understanding the proof that asymptotic stability implies the existence of a strong Lyapunov function. Taken from the book "Differential Dynamical Systems", chapter 4, by James Meiss. The definitions are:
[image]

[image]

[image]

and the theorem is:
[image]

is a strong Lyapunov function. This is the start of the proof: [image]
I don't understand how asymptotic stability implies there exists such a "uniform" time $T(\rho)$. I do understand how for all $x\in U$ there exists some time $T(\rho, x)$ but don't understand how there exists a uniform $T(\rho)$ which does not depend on $x$.

Comment: It seems correct if the set $U$ is bounded - you can take the upper bound. It is not valid if $U$ is not bounded; in such a case, $T$ must depend both on $\rho$ and the initial value $x$.

Comment: @Arastas But how would boundness of the set guarantee us a  uniform bound? Even if U was compact, we don't necessarily know that $T(\rho, x)$ is continuous as a function of $x$.

Comment: If you can upperbound $\|x\|$, then you can also upperbound $T(\rho,x)$

Comment: @Arastas how exactly? Sorry for not getting it.

Comment: Suppose for scalar $x$ you have $\phi_t = e^{-t}x$. Then $T(\rho,x) = \max(0, \ln(|x|) - \ln(\rho))$. If you know that $x\in U \implies |x| \le C$ then your upper bound is $T_u(\rho) = \max(0, \ln(C) - \ln(\rho))$. I.e.,  $T_u(\rho) \ge T(\rho,x)$ for all $x \in U$.

Comment: When mentioning some material, like here, it is often beneficial to mention what book, article, etc. it is.

Comment: @KBS Sorry for not mentioning. I edited the question. Differential Dynamical Systems by James Meiss

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you mean correctly, your confusion arises from the sentence

> Indeed, asymptotic stability implies that for any $\rho>0$ there is a time $T(\rho)$ such that for any $x\in U$, $|\phi_t(x)-x^*|<\rho$ whenever $T>T(\rho).$

and you are wondering why $T$ doesn't depend on $x$. This is actually a combination of the *definition* of [asymptotic stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems) and $\epsilon-\delta$ *definition* of limit. If you follow the link, you read:

> The equilibrium of the above system is said to be asymptotically stable if it is Lyapunov stable and there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\|x(0)-x_{e}\|<\delta$, then $\lim _{t\rightarrow \infty }\|x(t)-x_{e}\|=0$.

We can see that what the book means by $x\in U$ is actually equivalent to existance of a positive $\delta$ such that $\|x-x_{e}\|<\delta$. And also note that $\lim _{t\rightarrow \infty }\|x(t)-x_{e}\|=0$ is equivalent to the existence of a $T(\delta)$ —**not** a $T(\delta,x)$— such that $\|x(t)-x_{e}\|<\delta$ whenever $T>T(\delta)$.

Comment: I would like other answers as well, but gave you the bounty because why not

Comment: @Algo I would like to know if there is anything I am missing and how I can improve the answer. Thanks